# how to get rid of popup blocker for windows.open

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using windows.open to open a page like this:

```
 window.open("PlayAPI?CallIDno=" + CallIDno + "&PASSWORD='" + encodeURIComponent(PASSWORD) + "'");
```

but I am getting popup blocker error.

On other page I got this code but dont gett popup blocker error.

Comment: http://www.ehow.com/how_7340377_detect-blocker-browsers-using-javascript.html see if this helps, if it works you can use an alert for your users stating please allow popup for this site

Comment: You can not just get around a pop up blocker. How are you opening it?

Comment: One site I "used" to visit had a lot of popups - I no longer visit that site.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of following script to check popup is blocked or not

```
var w = window.open('http://google.com');
if(!w) { 
   //an alert in this example
   alert(' pop-up blocker is enabled. ');
}
```

but you cannot open up window if the popup is blocked , so to avoide it you can create your own custom popup using jquery like this  : [**Jquery Dialog**](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) or [Top 10 jQuery Modal Box Plugins](http://web.enavu.com/tutorials/top-10-jquery-modal-box-plugins/) which will allow you to provide model popup window to user.